Google Sheets Data Entry Form Not Working
I am a special education administrator and new to my school this year.  We have to schedule hundreds of meetings a year and need a better way to do it. I have never coded before so this is all new to me.
I have set up a Google Sheet for my scheduler.  Individuals will submit meeting requests via the form, which will copy over to a different sheet.  I have the script working to copy the information.  However, the dropdowns/checkboxes on the form and receiving sheet are causing troubles.  When the script drops the values on the new sheet, it puts it on the first totally blank (no dropsdown/checkboxes) rather than putting them on the first "empty" line.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1InEy_5GlyV1t2nFBCVStVur70scXBAfkgPJ2wQie3EY/edit?usp=sharing
The other functions (ClearCell, Archive Completed, and Sorting) are workign fine.
   function Submit() {
    const ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
    const datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("In-Progress");
    const values = formSS.getRange("C6:C34").getValues().flat();
   datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 29).setValues([values]);  
   ClearCell();
   }


Your file link needs permission to see and edit

In your situation, how about changing the method for retrieving the last row? So, how about checking the last row of column "A" as follows?
Modified script:
function Submit() {
  // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  const datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("In-Progress");
  const values = formSS.getRange("C6:C34").getValues().flat();
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(1) + 1, 1, 1, 29).setValues([values]);
  ClearCell();
}

By this modification, when this script is run, the values are put into the last empty row of column "A".
Note:

In this case, the last row of the column "A" is checked. If you want to check another column, please modify 1 of get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(1) to your situation.


That worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!  You are a lifesaver!

@Bryce Lauritzen Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
